# how To detect that cgaffinetransformrotate method is rotating the clockwise or anticlockwise?

Tags: iphone, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I need to figure Out that thorough the Cgaffinetransformrrotate I am rotating the view towards the clockwise or anticlockwise.

how it is possible?

Comment: i am rotating this method through the help of pangesture

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( positive value );
```

will rotate the view clockwise, and

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( Negative value );
```

will rotate the view Anti clockwise,

Comment: I don't think this answer is entirely correct. Try rotating something 180 degrees (PI radians). Then try with -180 degrees (-PI radians). It will be anticlockwise both times.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some thing like this

`YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 270.0/180*M_PI );`

I think rest of the thing you can figured out..

Answer (score 0):

The angle, in radians, by which to rotate the affine transform. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation. In Mac OS X, a positive value specifies clockwise rotation and a negative value specifies counterclockwise rotation.

Answer (score -1):

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( positive value );
```

will rotate the view clockwise, and

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( Negative value );
```

will rotate the view Anti clockwise,

But the document says:

> The angle, in radians, by which to rotate the affine transform. In
>   iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a
>   negative value specifies clockwise rotation.

does those contradict with each other?

Edit (by jcoleman): There is no contradiction since iOS inverts the display from what Mac OSX does. Therefore the directions are flipped.